# Tensor-Tensor Element-wise Division in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to divide a tensor by another tensor of the same shape element-wise using tf.div(). Here is my attempt at this:

```
tf.div((y-logits),y)
```

where:

```
y: <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0' shape=(2, 60) dtype=float32>
logits: <tf.Tensor 'Tanh:0' shape=(2, 60) dtype=float32>
```

The resulting tensor is output as "nan". This is true even if I change the dividend such that (y-logits) is replaced by y, for example (to make both tensors of the same type and isolate otherwise possible intricacies).

Additional background: I'm trying to create an accuracy measurement of the logits by subtracting the logits and target vectors, then dividing by the target vector (element-wise).

One last comment: `tf.div(logits,logits)` produces a non-nan value. Perhaps the fact that y is a placeholding tensor introduces an internal error somewhere? How might I be able to overcome this?

---

Edit (Clarifications):

1.) There are no NaN values in the y tensor. However, there ARE 0e+00s; this will create instances where zero is in the denominator.

2.) This is not a classification problem.. so, the `tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1),tf.argmax(logits,1))` isn't an applicable accuracy metric. I'm already using a `tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels= y,logits= logits))` to create the loss function. I'm just trying to compare the values in the target vector with the respective values in the output vector (logits), and thought the best way to do this was percent-error.

So.. it doesn't seem like I'll be able to use this method to determine accuracy. What other way might I be able to compute the accuracy? An RMSE technique?

Comment: Hmm, strange! Are you sure that all the elements in both tensors are non-nan values? Could you add those values here? Maybe that might give more clue

Comment: Hi @kmario23 , please see the Edits to the question. There are no NaN values in y.